# Não consigo manter o formato de uma data recebida de um dataframe

Tags: r, data

Eu tenho um dataframe com uma columa de data e outra coluna de hora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quero concatenar a data com a hora para ficar no formato de string `"2016-12-25T08:38:00"`

Inicialmente estava a tentar desta forma:

```
datainicial=vpnsessions2[1,3]
View(datainicial)
horainicial=vpnsessions2[1,4]
View(horainicial)
dataehora=paste(datainicial,horainicial,sep="T")
```

Mas o resultado que obtenho é:

```
17160T31080
```

Depois de pesquisar descobri que a parte da hora está em segundos, e a parte da data não tenho certeza, mas penso que é em dias.

Eu consegui resolver a parte da hora fazendo o seguinte:

```
td <- seconds_to_period(horainicial)
dataehorain=paste(datainicial,sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', td@hour, minute(td), second(td)),sep="T")
View(dataehorain)
```

Mas o resultado assim ainda não é satisfatório:

```
17160T08:38:00
```

A hora já aparece bem mas a data não.

Já tentei várias formas de tentar colocar a data direito, mas não estou a conseguir.

Ver imagem com o código e valores:
https://snag.gy/koJca2.jpg

Comment: Só uma sugestão: ao invés de colocar um link com uma imagem do código, é melhor [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código nela (como texto, e não como imagem). Veja mais detalhes [nesta resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485).

Comment: Um título melhor para essa pergunta é: "como somar um número de dias a uma data"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem razão. A data é o número de dias desde a "época unix". Para obter a data no formato que você deseja:

```
as.Date("1970-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d") + 17160
[1] "2016-12-25"
```

Comment: Se fizer dessa forma, ontenho o seguinte erro:

Comment: > dataehorain=paste(as.Date(datainicial, format = "%Y-%m-%d") + 17160,sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', td@hour, minute(td), second(td)),sep="T")
Error in as.Date.default(datainicial, format = "%Y-%m-%d") : 
  do not know how to convert 'datainicial' to class “Date”

Comment: > as.Date(datainicial, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
Error in as.Date.default(datainicial, format = "%Y-%m-%d") : 
  do not know how to convert 'datainicial' to class “Date”

Comment: qual o resultado de `dput(datainicial)`?

Comment: > dput(datainicial)
structure(list(DataInicioSessao = structure(17160, class = "Date")), .Names = "DataInicioSessao", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: e qual o resultado de `dput(horainicial)`?

Comment: > dput(horainicial)
structure(31080, class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs")

Comment: experimenta `paste(datainicial$DataInicioSessao, sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', td@hour, minute(td), second(td)),sep="T")`

Comment: É isso mesmo!!! Assim funciona. Obrigado =)